# Как в WooCommerce добавить подарок на пятый заказ?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Здравствуйте, весь интернет облазил в поисках решения. Кто-нибудь знает, как можно добавить подарок, например на 5-тый заказ? Плагины, хуки, всё что угодно никак не могу найти. Везде плагин 1+1 или на общую цену корзины, либо на количество, но не на количество заказов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Качаем https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/first-order-discount/

2) Правим код плагина ( у меня тут ещё +10% скидка для зарегестрированных пользователей)

```
function first_order_add_fee() {
    global $wpdb, $woocommerce;

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $customer_id = get_current_user_id();
    $orderNumCheck = wc_get_customer_order_count( $customer_id ); // count orders by current customer
    $options = get_option( 'first_order_add_settings' );
    $discountType = $options['first_order_choose'];
    $discountValue = $options['first_order_add_value'];
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
    $discount = $discountValue/100;

    $check5order = $orderNumCheck + 1;

    if ($check5order % 5 == 0) {

        $product_id = 1802;
        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];
                        if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                            $found = true;
                    }
                    // if product not found, add it
                    if ( ! $found )
                        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
                } else {
                    // if no products in cart, add it
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
                }
        }

        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Скидка 10%', -$subtotal*$discount );

    }
}

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        if ($value["product_id"] == "1802") {
            $currPrice = $value['data']->price;
            $currQuant = $value["quantity"];
            $totalPrice = $currPrice * $currQuant;
            $salePrice = $totalPrice - $currPrice;
            $salingPrice = $salePrice/$currQuant;
            $value['data']->price = $salingPrice;
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','first_order_add_fee' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну не весь Интернет облазили, это точно :)

Вот, например, [WooGift](https://codecanyon.net/item/woo-gift-advanced-woocommerce-gift-plugin/10685086). Он платный, но 1500 руб - невеликие деньги, да и слова "бесплатный" в вопросе не было, а фраза "все, что угодно" - была :)

UPDATE

С плагинами сложно, давайте кодить.

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'action_add_to_cart');

function action_add_to_cart(){
    global $woocommerce;

    // Все заказы текущего пользователя
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
    ) );

    // добавить подарок в корзину
    if ( ( $customer_orders % 5 ) == 0) &&
     ( $customer_orders > 0 ) ) {
        $gift_id = xxx....
        $product = wc_get_product( $gift_id );
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product, 1);           
    }
}
```

Код не тестировал, просто как общая идея.

Comment: Ооо я тоже обрадовался, когда его нашёл) Он у меня установлен, и перед глазами. Как там можно это реализовать? Там есть реализация, при X количестве товаров. Самая загвоздка в том, что мне нужно не на 5-тый товар добавленный в корзину, а при Х совершённых заказов. То есть на 5-тый заказ, должен быть подарок...

Comment: Мда, а по описанию-то должно там быть...

Comment: ну а вот такой? https://codecanyon.net/item/loyalty-rewards-for-woocommerce/2588711

Comment: Если затык с плагинами, то надо пробовать свой код. Набросал пример в ответе.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь и за то, что не остались равнодушным) Ниже напишу решение, вы думали в правильном направлении)